# Why does outputting bits inside of an "if" or "when" always output 0? MySql 5.7

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, mysql-5.7

I've been working with some bit columns. I have to select one column or another based on a third column. *That is not my question*.
Here's a simplified example to show what I've been encountering.

```
CREATE TABLE Testing (
ColType TINYINT(6),
Type1 BIT(1) DEFAULT b'0',
Type2 BIT(1) DEFAULT b'0'
);
```

Note that ColType is usually joined in via foreign key in the "real world" scenario.

```
INSERT INTO Testing
(ColType, Type1, Type2)
VALUES
(1, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 1),
(1, 1, 0),
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 0, 0),
(2, 0, 1),
(2, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1);
```

This creates all the possible combinations of the 3 columns. The following is the queries I've run using this data.

```
SELECT 
*,
IF(ColType = 1, Type1, Type2) Output1,
(CASE WHEN ColType = 1 THEN Type1 ELSE Type2 END) Output2,
IF(ColType = 1, CAST(Type1 AS SIGNED), CAST(Type2 AS SIGNED)) Output3,
IF(ColType = 1, Type1=1, Type2=1) Output4
FROM
Testing;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Describer
SELECT
*,
IF(ColType = 1, Type1, Type2) Output1,
(CASE WHEN ColType = 1 THEN Type1 ELSE Type2 END) Output2,
IF(ColType = 1, CAST(Type1 AS SIGNED), CAST(Type2 AS SIGNED)) Output3,
IF(ColType = 1, Type1=1, Type2=1) Output4
FROM
Testing;

DESCRIBE Describer;
SELECT * FROM Describer;
```

The results are:

```
ColType  Type1  Type2  Output1  Output2  Output3  Output4
1        0      0      0        0        0        0
1        0      1      0        0        0        0
1        1      0      0        0        1        1
1        1      1      0        0        1        1
2        0      0      0        0        0        0
2        0      1      0        0        1        1
2        1      0      0        0        0        0
2        1      1      0        0        1        1
----------
Field    Type            Null  Key  Default Extra
ColType  tinyint(6)      YES
Type1    bit(1)          YES        b'0'
Output1  int(1) unsigned YES        b'1'
Output2  int(1) unsigned YES        NULL
Output3  int(1)          YES        NULL
Output4  int(1)          YES        NULL
----------
ColType  Type1  Type2  Output1  Output2  Output3  Output4
1        0      0      0        0        0        0
1        0      1      0        0        0        0
1        1      0      1        1        1        1
1        1      1      1        1        1        1
2        0      0      0        0        0        0
2        0      1      1        1        1        1
2        1      0      0        0        0        0
2        1      1      1        1        1        1
```

My question is: why do certain versions of this query work and others not? I would expect the temp table to be holding the same values as shown in the first select, but that's clearly not the case. So why is there all of these mismatches of data?

**Edit:**
I'm using MySql Workbench 6.3.6 Community on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

testing it on sqlfiddle.com 
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e8bda0/1
Type BIT returns true/false instead of 0,1 maybe when it tries to cast true/false to a number, they all end up being zero.

Comment: You are testing on version 5.6. The question is about version 5.7. The difference in output is visible. What exactly makes the output all 0, and why is it not like that when using the same `select` to create a table? I don't really see how this answers the question.

Comment: Your fiddle shows that's not the case (at least for MySql 5.6). When casting the bit to a signed you see it properly going to 1 or 0 (as I showed in my question). I found it interesting that this behavior isn't the same in 5.6; the bits returned in the if statement are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to do with the fact that when you SELECT you're selecting all 4 outputs with `ColType = 1`
and when you insert the last 2 columns are based on `ColType = 2`...?
Your select and your insert are not identical? (possibly more cut and paste errors?)
Also there is no column for `Type2` from your Describe statement... I am starting to think you're cut and pasted the results from different places and the result your pasted could be for a different statement.

Comment: My bad there, I had copied an old query, but I used the right output. I've updated the query to be correct. This still doesn't answer my question, however.
I would appreciate if you're going to answer a question a second time to leave up your old answer instead of completely editing your old one away.

Comment: Why does your DESCRIBE still not return the column Type2?